# Reading from a text file with python - first line being missed

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file called test which has the contents:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

I am using the following python code to read this file line by line and print it out:

```
with open('test.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        print(x.read())
```

The result of this is to print out the contents of the text file except for the first line, i.e. the result is:

```
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Does anyone have any idea why it might be missing the first line of the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `for line in x` iterates through every line.

```
with open('test.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        # By this point, line is set to the first line
        # the file cursor has advanced just past the first line
        print(x.read())
        # the above prints everything after the first line
        # file cursor reaches EOF, no more lines to iterate in for loop
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
with open('test.txt') as x:
    print(x.read())
```

to print it all at once, or:

```
with open('test.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        print line.rstrip()
```

to print it line by line. The latter is recommended since you don't need to load the whole contents of the file into memory at once.