# Looping through the content of a file in RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

How can I loop through the contents of a file within Robot Framework?

My file contents would be like this:

1001
1002
1003
1004

I want to read the contents one by one, assign it to a variable and then do some operations with it.

Answer (score 17):

Robotframework has several built-in libraries that add a lot of functionality. Two that you can use for this task are the [OperatingSystem](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/OperatingSystem.html) library and the [String](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/String.html) library.

You can use the keyword [Get File](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Get%20File) from the OperatingSystem library to read the file, and you can use the [Split to Lines](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/String.html#Split%20To%20Lines) keyword from the String library to convert the file contents to a list of lines. Then it's just a matter of looping over the lines using a [for loop](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.4#for-loops).

For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | OperatingSystem
| Library | String

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of looping over the lines in a file
| | ${contents}= | Get File | data.txt
| | @{lines}= | Split to lines | ${contents}
| | :FOR | ${line} | IN | @{lines}
| | | log | ${line} | WARN
```

Comment: The FOR loop is in the old syntax of robot framework. The new version does not required the ':'.

Answer (score 2):

This solve my issue same like yours !

```
${File}=    Get File  Path\\FileName.txt
@{list}=    Split to lines  ${File}     
:FOR    ${line} IN  @{list}
\   Log ${line}
\   ${Value}=   Get Variable Value  ${line}
\   Log ${Value}
```

I am reading from 'text' file and 'Get Variable Value' is part of builtin library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a list of different examples how to use FOR & While loops in your Robot Framework Test Cases.

http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-2.5.3/atest/testdata/running/for.txt

Comment: Thanks Mario, but it does not tell me how to read from a file directly and loop through the contents. For e.g. the way we do in shell scripts: for var in 'cat file`; do something done;

Comment: can i read through the file similiar to what is explained here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237464/reading-from-a-text-file-with-python-first-line-being-missed

Comment: You can read through the file using the robot.libraries.OperatingSystem library.  There's a particular method which fits your request:
def grep_file(self, path, pattern, encoding='UTF-8'):
Check out the library:
http://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/2.7.7/_modules/robot/libraries/OperatingSystem.html

Comment: FWIW, the link in this answer is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

My strategy, that I've used successfully with .csv files, would be to create a Python-based keyword that will grab the nth item in a file. The way I did it involved importing the CSV Python library, so to give a more complete answer I'd have to know what file type you're trying to read from.