# How can I remove a value from file using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I need to remove a value from file in local directory.

The format of the file is .txt. I need to remove a complete line.

How can I do this using Robot Framework?

Comment: What is structure of your file? Do you need to remove entire record (line)? Or only value from key = value pairs?

Comment: I need to an entire line from the file.

Comment: Do you know how to write python code?

Comment: It's been a long time I wrote and have very little time. Could you write something here?

Answer (score 4):

A similar question to this has been asked before: [Looping through the content of a file in RobotFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193216/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-robotframework). Using the example from this link I created a file called `test.csv` with the following content:

```
1001
1002
1003
1004
```

Then proceeded to create a robot file with the following code. It reads the csv file into memory, deletes that file and creates a new one with the same name. The proceeds to loop through the in-memory version and writes every line into the file with the exception of 1 line holding the value `1003`.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     String

*** Test Cases ***
Example of looping over the lines in a file
    ${contents}=     Get File     test.csv
    Remove File    test.csv
    Create File    test.csv    
    @{lines}=     Split to lines    ${contents}
    :FOR    ${line}    IN   @{lines}
    \    log     ${line}
    \    Run Keyword If    ('${line}'<>'1003')    Append To File    test.csv    ${line}\n
```

Although this example will work, the real question is whether you should do this in Robot Script. I agree with Bryan Oakley that this would be better suited for Python where you have more control over the file.

Comment: I was hoping to find another way. As you mentioned, I am considering writing python code. But I am a beginner here. A little help on python would be great.